# I keep on getting a infinite loop in my for loop with nested if

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, jframe

this is my while loop the big one then we have a for loop with a nested if the problem is that the code inside the if keeps on looping and crashes the program. when i run my code and add a existing id number to validate it it keeps on sending the error message that it exists and i can't put my hand where is the problem with the loop

```
while (exist>=0){
    exist=0;
    for(int i=0; i<idArr.length; i++){
        if(AddID.getText().equals(idArr[i])){
            exist=1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID already exists!", "Clinic System", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            AddID.setText("");               
            addName.setText("");
            DOBADD.setText("");
            Address.setText("");                              
            PhoneNum.setText("");
            GenderAdd.setText("");
            break;                                
        }                            
    }
    if(exist==0) {
        try{    
        myconn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        //mystatShop = myconShop.createStatement();
        //myresShop = mystatShop.executeQuery("INSERT INTO patient_test VALUES (?, ?)");
        String SQL= "INSERT INTO PATIENT_INFO  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstate = myconn.prepareStatement(SQL);
        pstate.setString(1,AddID.getText());
        pstate.setString(2, addName.getText());
        pstate.setString(3, DOBADD.getText());
        pstate.setString(4, Address.getText());                             
        pstate.setString(5, PhoneNum.getText());
        pstate.setString(6, GenderAdd.getText());

        pstate.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Insertion Successful");
        AddID.setText("");               
        addName.setText("");
        DOBADD.setText("");
        Address.setText("");
        GenderAdd.setText("");
        PhoneNum.setText("");

        myconn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while argument says `while (exist>=0)`

 so according to the code exist value is always going to be equal or more than 0. So loop will never end.

 Put like this

 `while (exist>0)`

Also I don't see a reason to use nested loops. You can loop through the array using for loop only.

Comment: Did it but still keeps on giving out the error message        
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID already exists!", "Clinic System", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

Comment: i tried initializing exist=1 and 0 but still same errors

Comment: why do you need a nested loop for this? as i see while loop is not needed. just loop through the idArr[] array with for loop once.

Comment: Thank you I removed the while loop and it worked